# Kalmeo - KUIX: How to fix widget size

Tags: java-me

I'm developing a project and I created a table: 5 row , 3 columns. I want to fix column width. How I can? I try : Min-size but not work.

```
<screen style="align:fill-left;layout:inlinelayout(true, fill);bg-color: white">
<container style = "min-size: 70 0; align: center; bg-color: red;">
    <text >test 1: width 70 </text>
</container>

<container style = "min-size: 120 0; align: center; bg-color: black;">
    <text >width 120</text>
</container>

<container style = "min-size: 50 0; align: center; bg-color: blue;">
    <text >width 50</text>
</container>
```